# Do you add still use 네/당신 when using the conjugation 어때?

Tags: conjugation

I am just a bit confused when using 어때, I have read in some blogs online that some of them no longer uses "your" or 네/당신 when using 어때.

Example: 
Do I use 형은 어때 or 네 형은 어때? when I'm asking about my listener's older brother? By using 형은 어때 does it automatically means I am asking about *your* older brother? 
Reason that I am a bit confused is that when 형은 어때 is translated to my native tongue or also in English, it just means "How is brother".

감사합니다!

Comment: *The context is always important.* When the listener knows that 형 refers to "**your** older brother", you do not have to add 네. 형 can also refer to "**my** older brother." "어때?" is ambiguous as well, so you will have to edit your question if you would like more detailed answers. 당신 is a difficult word to use in conversation; unless the listener is your wife/husband, it may be offensive to the listener. I would not encourage any language learner to use 당신.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still getting around with using honorifics and formal sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Korean is a very contextual language, meaning that you can leave out a lot of parts of the sentence *if* it's obvious what you mean from who you're talking to, or what you're looking at, or what you were just talking about... or anything else that gives context to what you're saying.

> By using 형은 어때 does it automatically means I am asking about your older brother?

If it's fairly clear that older brother is the only older brother you could be talking about, yes. Otherwise, no, and you might want to specify whose older brother you are talking about to avoid the risk of being misunderstood.